# iOS ARKIT How to show circular image/model instead of PlaneGeometry while moving camera around?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, arkit, sceneview

I am trying to make a small AR based iOS App, In which I have to detect a plane and when user taps on that plane I have to place an Object. Pretty simple? But Instead of showing Plane while user is roaming around with Camera, I have to show a circle, not a plane.
I have followed [this](https://blog.markdaws.net/arkit-by-example-part-2-plane-detection-visualization-10f05876d53) tutorial, and I am able to show plane but I need to show circular Image/model/node etc.

In tutorial's video you can see a grid, I need to replace that grid with circular image. I tried to give my own Image but then it started showing me a full circle image and a half circle image.

Answer (score 0):

Seeing your code where you replaced the grid with a circle would be valuable. My best guess there is that your circle is on a rectangular plane and so it is repeating the image. Try making your plane a square.

Rather than use SCNPlane as the primitive have you could also try using a different primitive. SCNCylinder looks promising. You could make a cylinder with a small height and that would give you a circle. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scncylinder